# Python: Clicking a hyperlink button with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm writing a python script to grab my bank account details using `urllib`.

To access the login page, there is a hyperlink button present on the page. How can I get my script to click that button or indeed bypass it?

Please, any help me on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using urllib you can't perform a click on an `<a>` tag. You may want to look into `selenium-webdriver` for that matter.

You can fetch its `href` attribute value and then call the `urllib.urlopen(path)` function (make sure `path` variable contains the full path and not the relative path).

Comment: href having javascript like below
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="login_button" onclick="fnShowContent('errorCode','english')"> LOGIN</a>

Comment: In that case, using selenium-webdriver would be a better option.

Comment: Basically, when that `<a>` tag is clicked, the JavaScript function `fnShowContent('errorCode', 'english')` is called. `urllib`cannot execute a JavaScript function since it does not simulate a browser.

Comment: Second option, would be to observe the request sent when the `<a>` tag is clicked and then simulate a similar request in `urllib`.

P.S.: @Ruben gave a good suggestion. Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to Jason's answer that if you're going to pass `login data` you might want to step away from `urllib` and use `requests`.

I would find the `url` of the page that has the login `form` and use `requests` there.